# Sensitivity of exponential map to the continuous perturbations of smooth metrics.

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Consider the exponential map $exp_p$ at point $p$ on the complete Riemannian manifold $M$ with a smooth metric $g$. How does this map change under continuous perturbations of $g$ by smooth metrics?

Informally speaking the question can be reformulated as follows:

If the metric is not $C^\infty$ smooth then the regularity of a single geodesic is roughly +1 higher than the regularity of a metric. Does the same hold for perturbations of the exponential maps?

Comment: I changed Hoelder to continuous in the original formulation, as it is more appropriate for the actual purposes.